# Why is the pop-up 'about this tag' not displayed on the tags tab pages?

Tags: feature-request

Currently I have to click on the tag to display questions using the tag. 
And I only from that page I can hoover over the tag and select **About this tag** to see the wiki, if it has one.

Of course other ideas to see the definitions of all the tags would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to have the about this tag link with the tag description and other links for the tag so that everything is together.  From the tags tab if you click on a tag you see questions, the description and all the links.  If the about this tag link was placed in the tags tab page then it would not be as clear that the other information exists.

Comment: Thanks. I mainly use a wildcard tags like sql* to filter newest or active questions. So I didn't recognize that clicking on a tag will display a page including its description.